# Blade WordPress - custom page type not displaying pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, laravel-blade

I am trying to get pagination to work on a custom page template I made that is meant to show all posts (it will be an archive landing page once I'm done).

I have things set up to show a set number of posts per page using `wp_query. The correct number of posts display, their links works, but I cannot get pagination to work successfully.

If I use what I setup below, I get an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected end of file in web/app/uploads/cache/0cefb280e2bc87c5c0311d7606b77c153f8da2b0.php on line 531`

I've tried:

- setting WP_CACHE to false in the `wp-config` file
- tried setting `prev_text` and `next_text`to true
- excluding `$paginate_links`section
- deleting the `cache` folder in question (it just gets recreated)
- adding `@php wp_reset_postdata() @endphp` before the closing `@endwhile` but that gives me an unexpected end of if error
- using `{!! get_the_posts_navigation() !!}` just to see what that would do

I am totally stuck--I haven't come across something like this before with WP (although I am new to Blade templates). I can get posts to display on this custom page template but can't setup pagination -- it's had me stuck all day so far.

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
      @php

        global $post;
            $args = array(
                'prev_text'      => false,
                'next_text'      => false,
                'format'         => 'page/%#%#posts'
            );

      @endphp
      <div class="news-page-content">
        <div class="max-wrap">
          <div id="article-list" class="article-list-container">

            <div class="article-list">
              @php
                global $wp_query;

                  $wp_query = new WP_Query ( array(
                    'post_type'          => 'post',
                    'post_status'        => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'     => 4,
                    'orderby'            => 'DESC',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> true,
                    'nopaging'           => false,
                    'paged'              => true
             ));
              @endphp
              @if( $wp_query->have_posts() )
                @while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) @php $wp_query->the_post() @endphp
                <div>
                  <a href="{{ get_the_permalink() }}">

                    <h3>{{ the_title() }}</h3>
                    <h4>{{ get_the_date( 'm/d/Y' ) }}</h4></a>
                </div>
                @endwhile
                  @php wp_reset_query() @endphp
              @endif
              <div class="bottom-pager">
                    <div class="prev-next">@php posts_nav_link(' ','PREV PAGE','NEXT PAGE') @endphp</div>

                    <div class="pager">
                        {!! paginate_links($args) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding is that `paginate_links()` works with the `global $wp_query`, thus you will run into issues using a custom query. Can you try the following?
instead of doing this

```
$postlist_query = new WP_Query ( array(
```

Can you maybe adjust the `global $wp_query`

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query ( array(
```

**ALSO:** don't forget to reset the query once you're done with it, by using `wp_reset_query()` after your loop

---

**Disclaimer:** i'm generally opposed to changing the `global $wp_query` but it has it's use cases.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post to what I think is what you mean. I tried it but still had issues. Putting the wp_reset_query() after the loop and got an `unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)` error. Moving it after the end of the if statement does not work either (and probably shouldn't anyway)

Comment: looks like you're missing `@endphp` on this line: `@while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) @php($wp_query->the_post() ) @endphp`

Comment: Ok, did that...still no pagination showing up, though. I have no clue as to why--I feel like everything should be correct but nope--still no pagination